# Using Magento as an SSO provider

Tags: php, magento, single-sign-on, token, silverstripe

I have two sites I want to be connected with SSO. One is a store, using Magento, and I would like this to be the "source of truth" that holds all the members and will handle the authentication. The other is a marketing site using a CMS (SilverStripe), and I would like it to persist the session when the user changes from one site to another.

My back-of-the-napkin thinking is that links from the Magento store to the marketing site will pass a token in the request, and the marketing site will be able to validate that token using some kind of endpoint in Magento.

Disclaimer: I have no experience with Magento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build a SSO integration using the [SAML standard](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language)

SilverStripe has a [SP module](https://github.com/antons-/silverstripe-ssp), 
Magento has 2 SP Modules ([1](http://cmsmart.net/magento-extensions/sixto-martin-saml-single-sign-on-magento-extension)) and ([2](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/single-sign-on-by-wizkunde.html))

Then you will need to connect both SPs with a [simpleSAMLphp IdP](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp) that you may deploy, this IdP may use Magento or SilverStripe databases as authentication source.

See this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKTRkSEyUIA

Notice: I'm the developer of one of the Magento SAML SP extension.

Comment: Great response. Thank you.

Comment: Now available a SAML extension for Magento2: https://marketplace.magento.com/sixtomartin-onelogin-module-saml2.html